# Segmentation Fault when using Linked Lists and Char arrays

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, arrays

I'm struggling through my programming homework and need a hand with Linked Lists.  Basically we have to create a program that contains certain functions to manage linked lists.  Fairly standard.  I tried it last week and just couldn't get it.  I'm trying to get it working this weekend and was making good progress until I ran into segmentation faults.

```
struct STUDENT
{
  char *FirstName;
  char *LastName;
  char *PUID;
  int age;
  struct STUDENT *next;
};
```

This is the structure I'm trying to use.  The first three values are char arrays and the fourth is just a number.  Following this I tried to declare a starting and current node globally.

```
struct STUDENT *head = NULL;
struct STUDENT *curr = NULL;
```

Following this I have my create node function, which takes a user input and puts it into the list.

```
void *createListNode()
{
  char first[MAXNAME];
  char last[MAXNAME];
  char ID[MAXID];
  char *pfirst;
  char *plast;
  char *pID;
  int tage;
  struct STUDENT *temp = (struct STUDENT *) malloc (sizeof(struct STUDENT));

  printf("Enter a first name: ");
  scanf("%s", first);
  pfirst = first;
  printf("entered name: %s\n", pfirst);

  printf("Enter a last name: ");
  scanf("%s", last);
  plast = last;
  printf("entered name: %s\n", plast);

  printf("Enter the Purdue ID: ");
  scanf("%s", ID);
  pID = ID;
  printf("ID: %s\n", pID);

  printf("Enter an age: ");
  scanf("%d", &tage);
  printf("age: %d\n", tage);

  temp->FirstName = strdup(first);
  printf("first\n");
  temp->LastName = strdup(last);
  printf("last\n");
  temp->PUID = strdup(ID);
  printf("id\n");
  temp->age = tage;
  printf("age\n");
  temp->next = NULL;
  printf("next\n");

  if (curr == NULL)
    {
      printf("inside if\n");

      head->next = temp; //-------SEGMENTATION FAULT---------------------

      printf("line 107\n");
      head = curr = temp;
      printf("line 109\n");
    }
  else
    {
      curr = temp;
    }

}
```

Background of what I'm done up to this point:
I was getting segmentation faults when I tried to assign my arrays to my 'temp' node, but by using malloc on it I solved that problem.  Using print statements, I've tracked the problem to the indicated line.  When I try to run the code, I get a segmentation fault.  I tried the same malloc code above on the 'head' and 'curr' nodes, but that gave me:

```
carlton@carlton-Inspiron-N7010:~/CNIT315$ gcc lab5.c
lab5.c:20:64: error: invalid initializer
struct STUDENT head = (struct STUDENT *) malloc (sizeof(struct STUDENT));
```

This is where I believe the problem is, but I've been searching and experimenting for several hours and haven't gotten anywhere.  And I just realized this is now a very long post.  Thanks for reading it through and I appreciate any push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `head` to `NULL`. You can't dereference `head` before assigning a valid pointer to it. `head->next = temp;` gives you a segfault because `head` is a null pointer.

Thus, you need to review this part of the code:

```
  if (curr == NULL)
    {
      printf("inside if\n");

      head->next = temp; //-------SEGMENTATION FAULT---------------------

      printf("line 107\n");
      head = curr = temp;
      printf("line 109\n");
    }   else
    {
      curr = temp;
    }
```

Since it seems like you want to insert at the end of the list, I would suggest something like this:

```
temp->next = NULL;
if (head == NULL) {
  curr = head = temp;
} else {
  curr->next = temp;
  curr = temp;
}
```

This makes `curr` always point to the last node, and `head` always points to the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong or do you set `head->next = temp;` but never set `head` to a valid object before?
You either have to initialize `head` with an 'empty' Student at the beginning or you just have to set `head = temp;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've defined the `head` variable outside the `createListNode()` function, here's the problem:

Memory is never assigned to it, since you have never called `malloc()`

Comment: @Filipe: your suggestion got rid of the segmentation fault.  I still feel like I need to use malloc() on my head node.  the last code box is showing what happened when I tried to use malloc() on the head node.  is that what you meant?  if so, do you see where I went wrong?